# O que é programação orientada a protocolo?

Tags: swift, paradigma-de-programação

Gostaria de saber, o que é programação orientada a protocolo? Escutei um professor comentar sobre esse tipo de programação, sobre esse paradigma,porém ficou meio vago.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 4):

É vago porque não há definição formal, não é algo universalmente aceito. Swift é uma linguagem que usa protocolos para generalizar operações, e no fundo protocolos são interfaces em outras linguagens, com pequenas diferenças. Portanto o termo se refere a isto, o que é estranho porque apenas um mecanismo dar nome para um paradigma todo me parece exagerado, por isso fora dos domínios das linguagens da Apple ninguém fala nisso. Objective C também usa.

O protocolo é como uma interface com implementações padrão, mais ou menos como ocorrem em Java 8, Kotlin e C# 8. Ela é uma forma limitada de herança e polimorfismo, quase como um *trait*. Mas vai além e funciona como extensão de tipos por valor.

Talvez tenham querido usar outro nome para não confundir com interface quando esta não aceitava implementação. Nesse ponto até estaria mais correto e interface agora é um termo errado, mas que não mudará porque está enraizado nas tecnologias que a usam, mesmo depois do mecanismo mudar. Estritamente quando mudaram o mecanismo deveriam mudar o nome, mas foi mais pragmático fazer assim.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).